# Paypal does not Call IPN Script when payment is made from paypal.co.uk

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have developed one regular paypal form along with IPN script(in PHP).
When I make the payment using sandbox, everything works fine and flawlessly !
But when the form goes live, it doesn't even call the IPN.

Please note that the live payment is made through paypal.co.uk..  and Form submits data to paypal.com.

So, I think this is happening due to paypal.co.uk.
Is it so ?
Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your IPN script is likely still configured to verify the IPN data  at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ instead of https://www.paypal.com/, which will cause it to fail, which in turn will cause the script not to get executed.

You can review individual IPN messages to were sent for your account in History > IPN History on your PayPal account overview as well.

Comment: hello robert. ! Thanks. .
Actually my IPN script is also configured for paypal.com . .
And in the begining of the script, i've also logged that call. . But i never get a log whenever payment is made. .

Comment: Did you have a look at History > IPN History within your PayPal account? What does it mention as the HTTP Status Code?

Comment: Actually the actual receiver is not me.So, I don't have access to his a/c.Though, I have requested to get these details. Is there any possibility of any other reasons behind this ?
thanks for your attention Robert ! :)

Comment: Moreover, is it necessary to TURN ON IPN at paypal profile for this feature ?

Comment: 1. Not really. I'd wait for these results, as that will indicate whether or not PayPal has at least delivered the messages or not.

As for your second question: it depends. If IPN is 'off', notify_url will work regardless. However, if IPN has become 'disabled' on the account because of a prior fault with the script, then you'll need to re-enable it first.

Comment: Hi.. thanks a ton :)
the issue is now fixed. actually the client's paypal a/c was enabled for another IPN script. so it was sending notification to that script only.(even using notify_url, I was not getting notifications).
but now it is fixed :)
thanks a lot for your support.